# Codemirror plugin Tinymce inline mode IndexSizeError

Tags: javascript, tinymce, codemirror, tinymce-plugins

I'm using tinymce in inline mode on a contenteditable div.

I have used the CodeMirror tinymce plugin before (not inline mode) with no issues, but it doesn't seem to work correctly in inline mode.
I've tried changing the config to `inline: false` and it works.

Clicking the **Source** button opens the HTML with CodeMirror and seems ok.
But when I click **Ok** to save it, it seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari it adds an `&#x0;` and I can't close the modal (however, I can see that it has changed the content of the editable div), clicking the **Ok** button again, it adds another `&#x0;` and console error. Clicking the cancel or X button just adds console error.

In the console I get `IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value` `tinymce.min.js:5724`

In Chrome, it seems to work but I still get a console error `The given range isn't in document.`

My tinymce config is below:

```
var tinymceEditText = tinymce.init({
        selector: '.editableEl',
        // target: ".editableElTinyMCE",
        // theme: 'inlite',
        inline: true,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap anchor media',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'template textcolor colorpicker hr fontawesome noneditable hr',
            'insertdatetime contextmenu paste save codemirror',
            'OBstock emoji_one'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'save undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | | code',
        toolbar2: 'bullist numlist outdent indent | template | hr | anchor link unlink | image media OBstock emoji_one fontawesome ',
        relative_urls: false,
        remove_script_host: true,
        templates: "/admin/JS/tinymce/js/tinymce/lists/template_list.php",
        external_filemanager_path: "/filemanager/",
        external_plugins: {"filemanager": "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        filemanager_title: "Uploaded Files", //the title of filemanager window default="Responsive filemanager",
        filemanager_sort_by: "name", //the element to sorting (values: name,size,extension,date) default="",
        filemanager_descending: 0, //descending ? or ascending (values=1 or 0) default="0"
        codemirror: {
            indentOnInit: true, // Whether or not to indent code on init.
            smartIndent: true,
            indentWithTabs: true,
            saveCursorPosition: false,
            path: '/admin/JS/codemirror-' + CODEMIRRORVERSION, // Path to CodeMirror distribution
            config: {           // CodeMirror config object
                theme: CODETHEME,
                indentUnit: 4,
                lineNumbers: true,
                mode: "htmlmixed",
                matchBrackets: true,
                autoCloseBrackets: true,
                autoCloseTags: true,
                matchTags: {bothTags: true},
                indentOnInit: true, // Whether or not to indent code on init.
                smartIndent: true,
                indentWithTabs: true,
                lineWrapping: true,
                paletteHints: false,
                lint: true,
                lintOnChange: true,
                showHint: true,
                HTMLHint: true,
                CSSHint: true,
                JSHint: true,
                getAnnotations: true,
                gutters: ['CodeMirror-lint-markers', 'CodeMirror-linenumbers', 'CodeMirror-foldgutter'],
                foldGutter: true,
                profile: 'xhtml', /* define Emmet output profile */
                extraKeys: {
                    "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete",
                    "F11": function (cm) {
                        cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
                    },
                    "Esc": function (cm) {
                        if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
                    }
                }
            },
            jsFiles: [
                'mode/php/php.js',
                'mode/htmlembedded/htmlembedded.js',
                'addon/edit/matchbrackets.js',
                'addon/edit/closebrackets.js',
                'addon/edit/closetag.js',
                'addon/fold/xml-fold.js',
                'addon/fold/comment-fold.js',
                'addon/edit/matchtags.js',
                'mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js',
                'addon/search/searchcursor.js',
                'addon/search/search.js',
                'addon/hint/show-hint.js',
                'addon/hint/anyword-hint.js',
                'addon/hint/html-hint.js',
                'addon/hint/css-hint.js',
                'addon/hint/xml-hint.js',
                'addon/hint/javascript-hint.js',
                'addon/lint/lint.js',
                'addon/lint/javascript-lint.js',
                'addon/lint/json-lint.js',
                'addon/lint/css-lint.js',
                'addon/lint/html-lint.js',
                'addon/customplugins/lint/csslint.js',
                'addon/customplugins/hint/htmlhint.js'
            ],
            cssFiles: [
                'theme/' + CODETHEME + '.css',
                'addon/dialog/dialog.css',
                'addon/hint/show-hint.css',
                'addon/lint/lint.css',
                'addon/fold/foldgutter.css',
            ]
        }
});
```

EDIT: I've now managed to recreate this in Chrome and Firefox, by opening the source editor, clicking cancel, opening the source editor again and clicking Ok. Different errors in the console though:

Chrome:
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 3.` `tinymce.min.js:5`

Firefox: 
`IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount` `tinymce.mins.js:5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to figure this one out be myself.

The issue wasn't with CodeMirror itself but actually tinymce's `setContent` function.

This fix for this was using the `insertContent` function instead and adding an extra setting in the tinymce.init

```
if(CMsettings.config.inlineFix) {
    editor.selection.select(editor.getBody(), true);
    editor.insertContent(codemirror.getValue().replace(cc, '<span id="CmCaReT"></span>'));
} else {
    editor.setContent(codemirror.getValue().replace(cc, '<span id="CmCaReT"></span>'));
}
```

This made the insert button work but the cancel button still had some weird behaviour with the cursor, so I ended up duplicating and modifying the whole plugin to remove the insert and cancel buttons, and add them myself in the html